# Wants an awk program to count the number of heavy atoms in a structural file- MOL2 file

Tags: awk

I have a 'bestranking.lst' in this format:

```
 37.55       6.00      24.98       0.00      -2.80      -3.90   26.675  './gold_soln_CB_FragLib_Controls_m1_9.mol2'                    'ethyl'
 38.45       1.39      27.36       0.00      -0.56      -2.48   22.724  './gold_soln_CB_FragLib_Controls_m2_6.mol2'  'pyridin-2-yl(pyridin-3-yl)methanone'
 38.47       0.00      28.44       0.00      -0.64      -2.42   20.387  './gold_soln_CB_FragLib_Controls_m3_3.mol2'  'pyridin-2-yl(pyridin-4-yl)methanone'
 42.49       0.07      30.87       0.00      -0.03      -3.24   22.903  './gold_soln_CB_FragLib_Controls_m4_5.mol2'  '(3-chlorophenyl)(pyridin-3-yl)methanone'
 38.20       1.47      27.53       0.00      -1.13      -3.28   22.858  './gold_soln_CB_FragLib_Controls_m5_2.mol2'  'dipyridin-4-ylmethanone'
```

Column 9 represents names of molecules. And column 8 represents the coresponding Mol2 structure files of these molecules.

I need an awk program to count the total number of HEAVY atoms in each molecule.  The heavy atoms are in column 2 of each Mol2 file. An opened Mol2 file looks something like this:

```
  1 C1          75.9844  97.5040  19.3570 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.0695
  2 C2          74.9992  96.8780  20.1442 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.1625
  3 C3          75.3743  95.9247  21.1091 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.0561
  4 C4          76.7311  95.5991  21.2853 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.1359
  5 C5          77.7134  96.2252  20.4983 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.0708
  6 C6          77.3397  97.1775  19.5344 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.1411
  7 C7          73.5585  97.2251  19.9557 C.2            1 SUB                0.7353
  8 N8          72.7698  97.3734  21.0597 N.2            1 SUB               -0.6704
  9 C9          71.6047  97.8943  20.9482 C.2            1 SUB                0.5895
 10 N10         70.7604  98.0475  22.1854 N.4            1 SUB               -0.6099
 11 C11         69.8867  96.8655  22.4153 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.0016
 12 C12         70.0298  96.1021  23.5863 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.1438
 13 C13         69.2027  94.9861  23.8019 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.0494
 14 C14         68.2349  94.6340  22.8465 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.1913
 15 C15         68.0885  95.3951  21.6742 C.ar           1 SUB                0.2110
 16 C16         68.9160  96.5114  21.4595 C.ar           1 SUB               -0.1465
 17 S17         70.9482  98.4291  19.4875 S.3            1 SUB               -0.2097
 18 O18         73.0950  97.3706  18.8479 O.2            1 SUB               -0.5679
 19 O19         67.1788  95.0628  20.7807 O.3            1 SUB               -0.4957
 20 H20         75.7049  98.2370  18.6140 H              1 SUB                0.1406
 21 H21         74.6259  95.4380  21.7188 H              1 SUB                0.1556
 22 H22         77.0170  94.8679  22.0255 H              1 SUB                0.1541
 23 H23         78.7539  95.9739  20.6351 H              1 SUB                0.1510
 24 H24         78.0936  97.6579  18.9305 H              1 SUB                0.1485
 25 H25         70.7725  96.3698  24.3234 H              1 SUB                0.1557
 26 H26         69.3139  94.4004  24.7027 H              1 SUB                0.1708
 27 H27         67.6005  93.7759  23.0159 H              1 SUB                0.1642
 28 H28         68.8033  97.0984  20.5601 H              1 SUB                0.1648
 29 H29         71.4000  98.2003  23.0547 H              1 SUB                0.4930
 30 H30         70.1464  98.9429  22.1082 H              1 SUB                0.4930
 31 H31         66.9217  95.7038  20.1074 H              1 SUB                0.4777
 32 H32         69.7912  99.0852  19.3144 H              1 SUB                0.3173
 33 ****        73.1012  97.0758  21.9550 LP             1 SUB                0.0000
 34 ****        73.6781  97.2587  18.0433 LP             1 SUB                0.0000
 35 ****        72.1288  97.6029  18.7367 LP             1 SUB                0.0000
 36 ****        66.3497  94.8209  21.2848 LP             1 SUB                0.0000
 37 ****        67.5235  94.2568  20.2995 LP             1 SUB                0.0000
```

I expect the program to open each mol2 file and do a  count of only the heavy atoms(ie C,N,O,S etc; excluding the hydrogens and ****) in column 2.

I expect the output to be in the same format as the 'bestranking.lst' file but with another column showing the total heavy atom count of each molecule. An output of only the 'molecule name' and 'heavy atom count' of each molecule will also be fine with me.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Generally speaking, people won't write your code for you, but will help you fix up an honest attempt at solving the problem.  So, the question will be "What have you tried?"  Also, which version of `awk` are you using? The trickiest part is opening a file while you're process another — look up the `getline` function.  It is good that you specified the input files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following bash script:

```
files=$(awk -f extractFiles.awk bestranking.lst)
cnt=""
for file in $files ; do
    cnt=$cnt$(awk -f comp.awk $file)":"
done
awk -v cnt=$cnt -f addCol.awk bestranking.lst
```

where `extractFiles.awk` is:

```
{
    gsub(/'/,"",$8)
    print $8
}
```

`comp.awk`:

```
! (($2 ~ /^H/) || ($2 ~ /^\*\*\*/)) {i++}
END {print i}
```

`addCol.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    split(cnt,a,":")
}
{ print a[NR], $0 }
```

---

### Update

Based on the comment: To count the heavy atoms in a given section of the file, try to change `comp.awk` to:

```
/\@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ { count=1;  next}
/\@<TRIPOS>BOND/ { count=0}
count && ! (($2 ~ /^H/) || ($2 ~ /^\*\*\*/)) {i++}
END {print i}
```

Comment: the script worked, at least for the information I provided.  But the problem is that, the opened Mol2 file has other information before and after the portion of interest shown in my question. Therefore, the script does the count to include other unwanted stuffs.  I wish the script could restrict the counting within two immediate lines that come before and after the shown Mol2 portion of interest. The two lines are '@<TRIPOS>ATOM'and 
'@<TRIPOS>BOND' respectively.